# how to make a conditional in where. SEQUELIZE mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

should fetch all teachers where the value 'search' is found in the coursesOffered array.

**table teacher**

name   lastName    dob              coursesOffered

juan     perez   2022/10/02     [ 'math', 'science' ]

marcos   smith   2022/10/02     [ 'history', 'literature' ]

**Query sequelize**

```
const search = 'math';

const teachers = await Teacher.findAll({
    where: should fetch all teachers where the value 'search' is found in the coursesOffered array.
})
```

Comment: What SQL datatype is the `coursesOffered` column?

Comment: the column has the data type JSON - DataTypes.JSON

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8853) you can find the right syntax. The issue is old and still open, maybe there is some bug. You could still give a try. If with the sequelize syntax is not working, you can still build a raw SQL query

Comment: I get an error with this syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `JSON_CONTAINS` function.

```
// When you are doing string search, make sure to wrap the search term with "".
const teachers = await Teacher.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.fn('JSON_CONTAINS', Sequelize.col('coursesOffered'), `"${search}"`)
})
```